# Making dependent picklist value default in VF page

Tags: picklist, dependent-picklist, default-value

On Opprotunity object there is Stage(standard) and Status__c(custom) picklist fields. Status(dependent) is dependent on Stage(controlling) field. I want to make Open defalut value for Status__c in one Visualforce page.

```
 <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName}"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Status__c}" />
```

How to do that?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set default values for controlling fields but not for dependent picklists. 
[Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_dependent_field_considerations.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

Comment: Status__c has already default value "Open" .As it is dependent field on stage, It is not working. PFA for screenshots

Comment: You can set default values for controlling fields but not for dependent picklists.  [Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_dependent_field_considerations.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

Comment: Welcome. You can  make it required field or write a workflow if default value is not select to make sure at least value selected for a field.